# Collapse xml-node-children from `xml.el` into a string

Tags: string, xml

An API I have used for years (via an elisp package)
recently started inserting formatting tags
(particularly for `<i></i>` italics)
into the 'ArticleTitle' field of entries.
The assumption that the node-child of 'ArticleTitle' field is a single string
is thus no longer valid,
causing trouble shortly downstream.

I think I need help in either A) stripping out the formatting tags
or B) joining the child-nodes into a single string
to restore function.

I attempted to document the context
in which this question arose
at https://github.com/jshoyer/pubmode/issues/3
(a fork of the original package)

Googling this subject
and reading the `xml.el` source code
have both proved difficult.
Advice on search query terms
or how to construct a minimal reproducible example would be welcome.
Perhaps basic elisp list manipulation (without requiring any further use of `xml.el`) would suffice.
I would prefer not to use other emacs tools beyond `xml.el`.